# Notification in Tizen wearable web app to display the UI of app running in background

Tags: notifications, tizen-web-app, wearables

In the tizen wearable web application that I am developing, I need my application to prompt a notification to the user every 10min to go into the same application and give some sort of input from the app UI.

I am currently using a simple status notification from notification API which gives a notification having link to the current application. When user clicks on it, the application is launched again (as it does according to description in simple status notifiation).

But I don't want the application to be restarted by clicking on the notification. Instead it should get the application running background to display on the watch UI.

Please let me know any possible solutions to achieve this.

Below is the code I am using right now.

```
        var myappInfo = tizen.application.getAppInfo();
        var notificationDict = {
                content : "Please enter your response.",
                iconPath : "images/icon.png",
                vibration : true,
                soundPath : "music/solemn.mp3",
                appId : myappInfo.id 

        };
        currentBatteryLevelNotification = new(tizen.StatusNotification("SIMPLE",
                "Your input required!", notificationDict);
        tizen.notification.post(currentBatteryLevelNotification);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing with your code, got some progress using:

[AppContextId](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/application.html&langredirect=1#ApplicationContextId)

```
 var myappInfo = tizen.application.getAppContext();
 //appId : myappInfo.id or muappInfo.appId
```

and Moving app to background:

```
document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
    if(e.keyName === "back") {
        try {
            tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().hide();
            //instead of tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
        } catch (ignore) {
        }
    }
});
```

config.xml:

```
<tizen:setting background-support="enable" encryption="disable" hwkey-event="enable"/>
```

Tip: If you don't add background-support for Web application, it just dies once you are on exit, It's not possible to get current state.

But I assume the answer is **No**. May be Notification API is not designed to launch running application I guess.